# Logical Error in Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, logical-operators

Simple calculator that needs to quit when "quit" "q" "exit" or "x" is entered. What need to change in the condition?

```
echo -n "Enter Number Operator Number [exit/quit if finished]"
read num1 op num2

if [[ "${num1,,}" =~ "quit" | "q" ]] || [[ "${num2,,}" =~ "exit" | "x" ]]
then
    echo -e "\nExiting `basename $0`, Goodbye!\n"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Okay it's a long program, but basically this part is where the user would enter a number followed by an operator and then another number, so a calculation can be made. But if the user enters one of the 4 options I mentioned, the program needs to quit. So if that condition is true, the program has to echo exiting and then quit. If not, go on to the calculation. I need that condition to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting what "or" means. It is not an or between different values but between different logical conditions.

I think this is what you want:

```
[[ $num1 =~ "quit" || $num1 =~ "q" || $num2 =~ "exit" || $num2 =~ "x" ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ ${num1,,} =~ (quit|q|exit|x) ]]
```

The special feature of `=~` over regular equality is that the right-hand side expression is interpreted as an extended regular expression.  `(quit|q|exit|x)` is such an expression which means any text which matches "quit" or "q" or "exit" or "x'.

Note that the features `[[` and `=~` require an advanced shell like bash.  Ordinary `/bin/sh` may not have these features.

If you want greater compatible, there are two options.  One uses the `[` (test) statement:

```
num1="$(echo $num1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
if [ "${num1}" = quit -o  "${num1}" = q -o  "${num1}" = exit -o  "${num1}" = quit -o  "${num1}" = x ]
```

The above expression is longer because we are limited to simple equality tests.  `-o` is the "or" operator for `[`.

The other option uses the case statement:

```
num1="$(echo $num1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
case "${num1}" in
    quit|q|exit|x)
        echo ""
        echo "Exiting `basename $0`, Goodbye!"
        echo ""
        exit 0
        ;;
esac
```

Simple shells do not have the `${var,,}` feature but, as shown above, the `tr` (translate) utility can do case conversion.

Note also in the last example above that I have replaced `echo -e` with three simple `echo` statements.  This is because many shells do not support the `-e` option for `echo`.

Comment: I think that is the problem I am having, my shell doesnt recognize [[ and +~, so I can't really tell where the logical error is.

Comment: @user3101059 I have updated the answer to show non-bash solutions as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been on this for a few hours already